# Quick question about hyperplanes!

Tags: linear-algebra

If we are given a hyperplane in r4 then is the dimension of the hyperplane 3? Also how do i know if something is a hyperplane e.g if i have an equation x+y=0 then is this a hyperplane, what equation does a hyperplane have in general ?

Answer (score 1):

A hyperplane is an analogous term for the 2-D manifold we call it plane, but in higher dimensions. In other words, it refers to higher dimensional analogs of a plane. Just like a hypersphere refers to higher dimensional analogs of sphere, or hypersurface refers to higher dimensional analogs of surfaces.

About the equation, well, it looks something like $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n=b$, you can also write it like $\alpha_1(x_1-a_1)+\cdots+\alpha_n(x_n-a_n)=0$ which has more geometric information in it.

Comment: Yes, but when I hear the terms hyperplane or hypersurface, there is generally the connotation that it is a codimension one linear subspace or submanifold lying inside some larger (usually linear or projective) space.  In this sense, I wouldn't call $\mathbb R^4$ a hyperplane unless it was sitting inside $\mathbb R^5$.

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, that is correct. Perhaps the hypersphere example is a bit misleading to be put in here because some authors consider a 4-D closed ball to be a hypersphere no matter what space it's lying inside, but I put it there to show how the word is formed from the point of view of English grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example a line, which is a one-dimenstional object exists as a hyperplane in two dimensional space. A plane is a two dimensional object and exists in three dimensional space.

Consider the fact that if a plane existed in two dimensional space, it would just be the whole two dimensional space.

The number of variables will tell you the dimension of the hyperplane + 1. So two variables = one dimensional hyperplane. Three variables (i.e. a plane in 3D space) = two dimensional hyperplane.